# Assembly - validating ISBN (logic error somewhere)

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm working on a project for a [college course](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/cs313.s13/project1.shtml).

First, I'm not asking for a complete solution to this.  I'm having trouble finding where I've gone wrong.  When I enter a valid ISBN, 3201541974, my program prints the "invalid" code block.  I would appreciate tips on any logic errors you can see, and I'd also love to know if there's a better way to debug than staring at all of my code at once.  I'm used to relying on simple print statements and break points.

Edit: the problem was here

```
L1_top:
        mov     al, [esi]               ; get a character
        inc     esi         ; update source pointer
        sub     al, 0
        add     ah, al
        cmp     ah, 11
    .......
```

The reason I'm subtracting 0 from al is because al is initially a char.  Subtracting '0' from al converts this to an int or w/e.  I mistakenly subtracted 0 instead of '0'

The correct line is

```
        sub     al, '0'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, I'd like to say that I'm actually your TA for this course, its good that you are just looking for help debugging rather then asking for the answer, but we do have office hours and we are pretty friendly.

I'm going to answer the easier question first. There is an easier way to find problems in your code, it is called gdb. Its basically just a debugger. It is really helpful to debug in this way because it allows you to see what is actually in your registers, and memory, as you run the program. Here is the link to some information about how to use it. I suggest that you read up on it because it is really helpful. [gdb help](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/cs313.s13/gdb_help.shtml).

Now onto the more complicated part.

- I don't see why you have msg10 or msg11, you can also get rid of them and msg5 when you understand the way the logic is suppose to be set up.
- In your error check you might want to compare eax to 11, and jump if it is equal. This way it will only have to process the logic if there are the right number of digits. (10 digits + new line)
- In your loop you should check if the value is between '0' and '9'(yes the apostrophes are important, they tell the computer that the values are ASCII rather then numbers) or 'X'.
- After you have that then you should check if the "sum" and "t" are greater then or equal to 11, subtract 11 if they are, and got through the whole loop 10 times, once for each character.

Comment: Wow, I'd already upvoted this answer having read the first sentence incorrectly, twice. Now that I've read it correctly, I want to upvote again...

Comment: Wow, thanks. I'm going to e-mail the professor a link to this just to give you kudos.  The reason i have msg 10 and 11 are actually because I was trying to figure out what was going on by inserting print statements, by copy/pasting and editing the 4 lines that work for the others, but that was causing fault segmentation or w/e error.

Comment: Your comment about the '0' being a character lead me to the answer.  I was subtracting 0 instead of the char '0' to convert from char to int.  My eyes caught that detail on the site after you said that.  Thanks a lot.  The rest should be easy to implement.  I'm taking down most of the code portion of this question so I don't get blamed for other students copy/pasting.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, "print statements" are not that easy to write - simply calling a "print_debug_out" function will change most of the relevant state (flags, stack, etc.). But you *can* write them and do it only once. Create a mini-library of debugging functions and macros!

I was also going to suggest `gdb`. Assemble with debugging information (-g) and use gdb to debug. You'll probably need to find a tutorial or a GUI wrapper, but it will be well worth your while to learn to use gdb (or another debugger, for that matter).

Note that you can set breakpoints in your source code as well as in a debugger. Simply use the `int 3` or `int3` instructions.

Comment: That's a great point, I completely forgot the mention the -g flag. Thank. gdb is actually on the server all you have to do is compile it with the -g flag when using the nasm command. load it with ld, then type `gdb a.out`, if you don't change the binary's name.